# Is there generic inheritance in python?

Tags: python, inheritance

I was wondering if there is generic inheritance in python.

For example,

```
Class A(object):
  def foo():

Class B(object):
  def foo():


Class C(<someParentClass>):
  def bar():
```

so effectively, I would like to do something like

```
  myClass1 = C()<A>
  myClass2 = C()<B>
```

Im guessing this is not possible in python, but is there any other way to have a similar effect?

Comment: Python doesn't even have generics. Generics only make sense when there are static types and you don't want to write the same code for several types. Python code always accepts any objects (although it can and will error later if the given objects aren't usable). What are you really trying to do?

Comment: Sounds like you should read about "mix-in" classes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's nothing preventing it. Everything in Python is essentially generic. Everything is runtime, including class statements, so you can do something like:

```
def make_C(parent):
    class C(parent):
        def bar(self):
            ...
    return C

myClass1 = make_C(A)
myClass2 = make_C(B)
```

If you want the C class to be a little more descriptive in name or documentation, you can assign the `__name__` and `__doc__` attributes, or use the three-argument form of `type()` instead of the `class` statement to create it.

Comment: Note, though, while nothing prevents a person from doing something like this, it isn't normal practice for Python. There are better, clearer, more Pythonic solutions to this issue. Generics are really a solution to a problem that doesn't exist in Python. Consider that in Python you can test your objects for the "foo" function easily and call it with the expected arguments regardless of parent classes.

Comment: I agree that generics are not a meaningful thing in Python, but creating a class in a function like this does have its uses. It's just a solution to a different kind of problem :)

Answer (score 2):

You could derive `C` from `object` and use

```
class MyClass1(A, C):
    pass
class MyClass2(B, C):
    pass
```

There are many ways achieving the exact effect you described, but I think defining `C` as a mix-in class is the most idiomatic approach.

Comment: If the intent is for C to specialize `A` and `B`, you should inherit from `C` first (or it won't be able to override methods defined in `A` or `B`.

Comment: @Thomas: I interpreted the OP's intent in the way that `C` extends `A` and `B`.  In his example, it does not overwrite any methods.

Comment: Yes, so did I. And I'm saying "you should inherit from C, or you will get different behaviour". If `C` extends `A` and `B`, it should come *before* `A` and `B` in the hierarchy.

Comment: @Thomas: Depends on the semantics you want.  I tend to put the actual base class first and the mix-ins later.  I usually don't want mix-ins to overwrite methods, and I definitely want the derived class to use the metaclass of the actual base class, not the one of some mix-in.

Comment: But if `C` is a *mixin*, it's not a *subclass*. It's different behaviour than the OP seems to want. It's not *extending* `A` or `B`. As for the metaclass, that's not how it works. The metaclass is determined by *all* the baseclasses; the most specialized metaclass is used (with a specialcase for classic classes, which always lose to a new-style class.) If the baseclasses have conflicting metaclasses (not counting classic classes), it'll be an error.

Comment: @Thomas: Thanks for resolving my misconceptions about metaclasses -- I must have got [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#__metaclass__) wrong some time back.  Is there any official documentation explaining this behaviour? -- As to what the OP wants: we just don't seem to know.  I don't think you are wrong, I just think there are multiple valid interpretations.

Comment: I don't think there's proper documentation on the details of metaclasses, unfortunately. Some of it is covered in PEPs 252 and 253, some of it in http://www.python.org/2.2.3/descrintro.html, but most of it's only obvious from experimentation or the source (and this particular part of the CPython source is *not* obvious :) As for the OP's intention -- I'm not even arguing about that, I was just pointing out the difference, and then later pointing out that your use of the word 'extending' does not accurately describe what your code actually does :)

Comment: @Thomas: Thanks for the pointers!  Helped me to find where I got the assumption that the first base is used to determine the metaclass from: [PEP 253](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0253/), search for "first base".  The PEP states that only the constructor of the first base class is called, and that it is up to this constructor to decide which metaclass to return.  According to the PEP, `type.__new__()` implements the behaviour you stated.  But from experimentation it seems the PEP is wrong and you are right -- I did not look at the source code yet.

Comment: @Thomas: I made a mistake in my experiments.  The PEP is right.  I also confirmed this by reading the source.

Comment: @Thomas: No, it doesn't.  None of your metaclasses overwrite `type.__new__()`, and `type.__new__()` indeed implements the behaviour you stated (see above).  Also, see the [relevant lines](http://paste.pound-python.org/show/8001/) from the current development version of `bltinmodule.c`.

Comment: I'm not sure how you think that changes what I said, sorry. The *mechanics* are such that type.__new__ will figure out which class to actually instantiate, but it still takes *all* baseclasses' metaclasses into account. As far as I can tell the only way to create a class the way you expect (ignoring the metaclasses of anything but the first baseclass) is by creating the class *without* those bases in a custom metaclass's `__new__`, and then re-assigning the real list of bases to the class's `__bases__`... which seems like it *should* be an error (and it may well be, in other implementations :)

Comment: @Thomas: I don't think we disagree in any way.  I'm just saying Python behaves exactly as specified in PEP 253, and your tests don't say otherwise.  (You can [make up silly examples](http://paste.pound-python.org/show/8003/) which the order of base classes matters for, but there probably aren't useful examples.)